# Packed file is much smaller

Tags: packing

Not a problem per se, but a client noticed a file I worked on was much smaller than the one they sent. I figured it was because I packed it, does packing delete stuff too?

Comment: You might have compression turned on too.

Comment: I have noticed when cleaning out duplicate images and such that it may take 2 or 3 times closing and reopening for blender to purge all of the data.